# select pegando os itens que estão no dia e hora atual

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Quero pegar os itens que sejam menor que a data e hora atual, mas quando executo o select da a mensagem de erro, not a valid month. No banco de dados a data esta configurada da seguinte forma, '25/09/18 10:23'.

```
SELECT * FROM v_tpl_acompanhamento WHERE 
coleta_plan = TO_DATE('25/09/18 12:19', 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta no [formato da data](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780), o correto seria 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI', você esta passando MM duas vezes, logo ele esta esperando duas vezes um mês.

Também lembrando, se você precisa comparar com a data atual, basta usar o Sysdate

Comment: Arrumei o select, coloquei o MI no lugar do MM mas mesmo assim ainda continua exibindo a mensagem de erro, not a valid month.

Comment: Consegui resolver, a forma que eu estava usando o select estava errada. O correto é formatar a coluna que eu quero com to_date e depois fazer a comparação, desta forma: SELECT * FROM v_tpl_acompanhamento WHERE 
TO_DATE(coleta_plan, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') = TO_DATE('25/09/18 12:19', 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI')